# Django issue with formset validation

Tags: python, django, validation, formset

I'm new to django and have been pulling my hair out on this one. A co-worker coded a manual post function that validates is_valid()=true, and I'm trying to move towards using the built-in validation by overriding the formset_valid function, but it's never valid.

I have this model.py:

```
class Assignment(PACSModel):
    course_id = models.IntegerField(unique = False)
    assignment_number = models.IntegerField(unique = False)
    assignment_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    start_date = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    due_date = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    end_date = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
```

This forms.py:

```
class AssignmentDatesForm(forms.ModelForm): 

class Meta:
    model = Assignment
    fields = [
    'assignment_number',
    'assignment_name',
    'start_date',
    'due_date',
    'end_date',
    ]

    widgets = { 'assignment_name' :forms.TextInput(attrs={'readonly':'readonly', 'class' : 'grey-text', 'size' : '25'}),
                'start_date' : forms.DateInput(format = '%m/%d/%Y', attrs ={ 'class' : 'datepicker'}),
                'due_date' : forms.DateInput(format = '%m/%d/%Y', attrs ={ 'class' : 'datepicker' }),
                'end_date' : forms.DateInput(format = '%m/%d/%Y', attrs ={ 'class' : 'datepicker' }),}

class Media:
    css = {'assignment_name': ('changeDates.css',)} 

AssignmentDatesFormSet = forms.modelformset_factory(
    model = Assignment,
    form = AssignmentDatesForm,
    extra = 0,
    )
```

manually iterating through the forms to display:

```
         <table class = "table table-striped table-condensed table-hover"> 

            <thead >
                <tr>
                    <th>Assignment Number</th>
                    <th>Assignment Name</th>
                    <th>Start Date</th>
                    <th>Due Date</th>
                    <th>End Date</th>                   
                </tr>               
            </thead>
            <tbody> 
                {% for t in form %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ t.assignment_number }}</td> 
                    <td class = "inputA">{{ t.id }} {{ t.assignment_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ t.start_date }}</td>
                    <td>{{ t.due_date }}</td>
                    <td>{{ t.end_date }}</td> 
                </tr>               
            {% endfor %}  

        </tbody>   

        </table>
```

and finally, the view is a class on top of ModelFormSetView where I have this simple post function to just test the validation:

```
    def post(self, request, course_id, *args, **kwargs):
    logging.warning("In Post with course_id: " + course_id)
    formset = AssignmentDatesFormSet(request.POST)
    if formset.is_valid():
        logging.warning("Formset Saved")
        formset.save()
    logging.warning(vars(formset))
    return super(EditDueDates, self).post(request, course_id, *args, **kwargs)
```

This is a simple formset with each form being an assignment where the user can change the dates (start date, due date, end date).

I am just trying to get it to validate so it will call formset_valid and I can do the saving/post processing. But everytime I get this error for each form:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>id<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

I don't get it at all. The vars(formset) dump has a hidden form-0-id input field that has the id (pk) set. I don't understand why it won't say it's valid.

What's more confusing is a co-worker got it to work doing almost exactly the same thing, what's more he didn't have to include the assignment_number field. It doesn't need to be displayed but if I don't have it in there it gives an error that it's required which is why it's included. Our tables are identical and all fields in the pgsql are required.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I'm not sure where to go about diagnosing this..

-Will

Comment: Which field is that error relating to? You should print `{{ t.errors }}` inside your loop.

Comment: From what I can tell it's the id field. The error says <li>id<ul class="errorLlist"><lie>Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.</li></ul>

Comment: I figured this out. I appreciate anyone reading through this as the error was right in front of me but took a co-worker to help me see it. I created a custom ModelFormView that did initial clearing of the db in the __init__ function. I didn't realize this was executing before a post as well. I overloaded the get instead to clear out the db and it worked fine. Why am I doing this? Because the db is really just a staging ground to house the data while it's being changed, that when saved, executes an api call to another system to update the data there.